# LinqToSQL InsertOnSubmit Issue

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, datacontext, insertonsubmit

I've class contact that has associate with class account and city. City has associate with class state, when I try to insert new contact data, the associated class is inserted too. How can this happen ? And how to fix it ?

Method InsertOnSubmit

```
    public void InsertOnSubmit<T>(T data) where T : class
    {
        lock (_lockObj)
        {
            using (DataModel dx = new DataModel(this._adapter.ConnectionString))
            {
                dx.DeferredLoadingEnabled = false;
                dx.GetTable<T>().InsertOnSubmit(data);
                dx.SubmitChanges();
            }
        }
    }
```

Add new contact

```
InsertOnSubmit(new Contact { Name = this.Name, Account = Session.Account, City = this.CurrentCity });
```

Note: object city, account, and state is from different datacontext. I use SQL Server Compact 3.5 as Database Server.

Log from console when dx.SubmitChanges() is fired

```
INSERT INTO [State]([Name])
VALUES (@p0)
-- @p0: Input String (Size = 0; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [Center America]
-- Context: SqlProvider(SqlCE) Model: AttributedMetaModel Build: 4.0.30319.1

SELECT CONVERT(Int,@@IDENTITY) AS [value]
-- @ROWCOUNT: Input Int32 (Size = 0; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [1]
-- Context: SqlProvider(SqlCE) Model: AttributedMetaModel Build: 4.0.30319.1

INSERT INTO [City]([StateId], [Name])
VALUES (@p0, @p1)
-- @p0: Input Int32 (Size = 0; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [10]
-- @p1: Input String (Size = 0; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [Los Angeles]
-- Context: SqlProvider(SqlCE) Model: AttributedMetaModel Build: 4.0.30319.1

SELECT CONVERT(Int,@@IDENTITY) AS [value]
-- @ROWCOUNT: Input Int32 (Size = 0; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [1]
-- Context: SqlProvider(SqlCE) Model: AttributedMetaModel Build: 4.0.30319.1

INSERT INTO [Contact]([AccountId], [CityId], [Name])
VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2)
-- @p0: Input Int32 (Size = 0; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [1]
-- @p1: Input Int32 (Size = 0; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [18]
-- @p2: Input String (Size = 0; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [Sarah]
-- Context: SqlProvider(SqlCE) Model: AttributedMetaModel Build: 4.0.30319.1

SELECT CONVERT(Int,@@IDENTITY) AS [value]
-- @ROWCOUNT: Input Int32 (Size = 0; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [1]
-- Context: SqlProvider(SqlCE) Model: AttributedMetaModel Build: 4.0.30319.1
```

Regards,

Brian

Comment: Could you clarify your question? Do you mean that you're trying to insert a new row in the table Contact and that this row will be linked to existing rows in the tables Account and Cities?

Comment: when new contact row is inserted the associated class is inserted to with duplicate value. Such when i add contact with account with name "Sarah" and City with name "Los Angeles". it will add sarah in table account and ad los angeles in table city. Now table account has two sarah and city has two los angeles. I set primary key of all table to autoincrement

Comment: It's a best practice to have only one Data Context per database. Is the PK set on the objects Session.Account and this.CurrentCity? You could set up directly the FK in the Contact object (ie new Contact { Name = this.Name, AccountId = accountId, CityId = cityId });